# I want to make network get request using kotlin multi platform for android and ios, how?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

how can I create a simple app that retrieve any data from server, I am stuck I don't know how I can start if anyone can help me?

Comment: I think ktor works on Kotlin/Multiplatform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ktor, which is a networking library from Jetbrains. See an example here:

https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/kpg/ktor_hack/shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/kampkit/ktor/DogApiImpl.kt#L38

The request needs to be made on the main thread in native, just FYI.